# hazelcast 5.3.6 kubernetes set to dns_lookup but client launched with kubernetes_api

Tags: java, hazelcast

Hazelcast creates a client in discovery mode kubernetes_api that tries to connect in an infinite loop and blocks the app start

I created a hazelcast instance with version 5.3.6 and set discovery strategy to dns_lookup the cluster starts perfectly using this discovery mode but then a client is launched hz.client1 [dev] using kubernetes_api as discovery mode, and it gets stucked as i have no RBAC,  and it is unable to get live cluster connection
How can I use also dns_lookup for this client? I tried to create a bean ClientConfigand set strategy to dns_lookup but it still tries to connect using kubernetes_api

[See hazelcast log creating hazelcast cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfrRK.png)

[See hazelcast log with cluster up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dn0R.jpg)

[See client trying to connect the kubernetes API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYLsg.jpg)

Comment: Check out this link. https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.2/kubernetes/kubernetes-auto-discovery.adoc#discovering-members-from-hazelcast-clients

Comment: fwiw - link does not work  (obviously it's been a while - but, I'm curious to see the info as I have the same issue at the moment)  :-)

Comment: been a while - let me know you found an answer to this - thx :-)